# Passing reference to QPixmap ctor

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

When I try to pass what appears to be a reference to my `QPixmap`, I get an error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘QGraphicsScene::addItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem (&)(QPixmap))’
```

The problem is that I don't know where this reference is coming from, though I'm guessing it's coming from the iterator.

```
void MainWindow::addItems(std::map<std::string, QString> * items)
{
    std::map<std::string, QString>::const_iterator current;

    for(current = items->begin(); current != items->end(); ++current)
    {
        QString cur = current->second;
        QGraphicsPixmapItem item(QPixmap(cur));
        _scene->addItem(item);

    }

}
```

If that's the case, is there a way to de-reference the `iterator`? Otherwise, what is it that I'm doing wrong?

**The code which calls it**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::map<std::string, QString> * items;

    items->insert(std::pair<std::string, QString>("ozone", ":/images/ozone_sprite.png"));

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.addItems(items);
    window.show();

    delete items;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've fallen foul of what's known as C++'s 'most vexing parse'. Specifically, this:

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem item(QPixmap(cur));
```

declares a function called `item` that takes a single parameter of type `QPixmap` and returns a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. To fix this, write:

```
QPixmap temp(cur);
QGraphicsPixmapItem item(temp);
```

See here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

As far as the error goes, note that you're trying to call `addItem` with an argument of type `QGraphicsPixmapItem (&)(QPixmap)` - that is, reference to a function taking a `QPixmap` and returning a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` (which is the type of the expression `item`).